# Leer json desde php(laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, json, php7, laravel-8

Como se podría acceder al `name` que está ubicado en league?

Pude acceder a `lastName` con esto:

```
$url = "https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/api/fut/item";
$response = Http::get($url);
$data = $response->json(['items']);

foreach ($data as $obj) {         
     $name = "nombre de jugador: ". $obj['firstName'] . '<br>';
     print ($name);
            
}
```

```
"items": [{
  "commonName": "Cristiano Ronaldo",
  "firstName": "C. Ronaldo",
  "lastName": "dos Santos Aveiro",
  "league": {
    "imageUrls": {},
    "abbrName": "ITA 1",
    "id": 31,
    "imgUrl": null,
    "name": "Serie A TIM"
  },

}],
```

Estoy obteniendo los datos de https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/api/fut/item

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De la misma manear que para acceder a firstName usas

```
$obj['firstName']
```

Para obtener el name que esta ubicado en league tienes que hacer

```
$obj['league']['name']
```

Eso sería para obtener solamente a el `name`, pero si quisieses obtener todos, podrias hacerlo a mano 1 a 1 o podrías hacer otro foreach igual al que has hecho con

```
foreach ($data as $obj)
```

pero esta vez con los datos de league. Algo así como

```
foreach($obj['league'] as $datoLeague)
```